Pulling commits from only one directory in a project
I have branch1 and branch2 in a Git-tracked project. There were several commits made in branch2 ahead of branch1 in directories directory1 and directory2. I need to push all files commited to directory1 from branch2 to branch1 but not to push any files of directory2 from branch2 to branch1. How can I implement this operation?
More specifically, how can I pull changes from only directory1 from branch2 standing on branch1?

I believe this is called "partial merge". There are questions and answers about it.

Without the commit history: git restore -SW -s branch2 -- directory1 && git commit. To preserve commit history: use git filter-repo

If you don't have a commit that contains changes to both directory1 and directory2 directories, then this will work:
git checkout branch1
for commit in $(git log --reverse --oneline $(git log -n 1 branch1 --pretty=format:"%H")...$(git log -n 1 branch2 --pretty=format:"%H") -- directory1/ | awk {'print $1'}); do git cherry-pick $commit; done

But if you have at least one commit that changes both directory1 and directory2 directories, then
git checkout branch2
git checkout -b branch2-new
git filter-repo --path directory2 --invert-paths --refs branch2-new
git checkout branch1
for commit in $(git log --reverse --oneline $(git log -n 1 branch1 --pretty=format:"%H")...$(git log -n 1 branch2-new --pretty=format:"%H") -- directory1/ | awk {'print $1'}); do git cherry-pick $commit; done

